# Fetch API display undefined js

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I try to fetch from https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/asset/list.json.

here my js code:

```js
<script>
let test;
fetch("https://js.cexplorer.io/api-static/asset/list.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    test = res.data.policy;
  })
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = test;
console.log(test); 
</script>
```

In homepage there is a div:

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

In Google Console I have correct response from the APIm but in the homepage I see undefined instead the value of API.
I don't have a lot of experience with js and API. I don't understand where is the error.

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that there is actually a property with `res.data.policy`
To make sure make a console for each property

```
console.log(res);
console.log(res.data);
console.log(res.data.policy);
```

You will understand which state causes undefined

Comment: There won't be at the time they are trying to assign the variable.